# Extending edge colourings

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

Suppose that $\Gamma$ is a connected locally finite graph with a uniformly bounded degree, i.e. there is a $d \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for every $v \in V\Gamma$ we have $\mathop{deg}(v) \leq d$. Using de-Bruijn Erdos theorem, such graph has an edge colouring using at most $d+1$ colours.

My question is the following: can a legal colouring of a finite connected subgraph be always extended to a legal colouring of the whole graph? Fore formally: given a finite connected subgraph $\Delta \leq \Gamma$ and a a legal edge-colouring $F \colon E\Delta \to \{1, 
\dots, d+1\}$ is there a legal colouring $\tilde{F} \colon E\Gamma \to \{1, \dots, d+1\}$ such that $\tilde{F}\restriction_{E\Delta} = F$?

I am assuming that the graph $\Gamma$ is vertex-transitive, if that helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, in the (vertex transitive, cubic) graph below, there is no way to colour the dashed edge using any of the 4 colours already present.

[image]

If you would like a strictly infinite example, the same idea works if you take a little piece of an infinite ladder:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the examples! Do you know, does the situation change if I assumed the finite subgraph Δ was a full subgraph, or even stronger, convex (with respect to the path-metric)?

Comment: The situation does not change if you assume that $\Delta$ is induced (full). Consider removing a single vertex $v$ from a square grid (d+1 = 4+1 = 5), and colouring the 8-cycle surrounding $v$ with edges that are alternately colours 1 and 2. 

Clearly, none of the edges incident with $v$ may be either colour 1 or 2. This leaves only 5-2 = 3 colours, but 4 edges. So the colouring cannot be extended. 

I don't know about convex subgraphs, I would suspect convexity doesn't help, but constructing examples is very hard.